# React-router history.push() has changed URL successfully but not re-render my JXS content to the right Route content with matched path

Tags: reactjs, react-router, history.js

1. I used to change page by rendering whole page's component in which way to use setState "currentPage:'xxx'" with switch case inside render to match the right parameter, so that it could render the 'xxx' 's content.

And these two days I was trying to use React-router to substitute this old way and it happened this situation between login-page and dashboard-page.

I used to put a submit function calling API to receive the result that decides whether re-render to dashboard-page

But now if I use  to re-render which  should display, it couldn't pass through the submit function (at least I don't know how to use

So I put history.push() into the submit function's API result, so that when result state is "true", history.push() would be execute.

But the problem happened here, that's, the history.push execute completely and URL has rightly changed to localhost:3000/dashboard but my page doesn't change at all.

2. I've the second question which is what's the advantage of using React-router compared to my old swich-case-render way?

By the way, I use the Create-react-app

here is my code

```js
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './index.css';
import axios from 'axios';
import './dist/css/adminlte.min.css';
import './plugins/fontawesome-free/css/all.min.css';
import './plugins/icheck-bootstrap/icheck-bootstrap.min.css';
import  { BrowserRouter as Router, Switch, Route, Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import Login from "./Login";
import Board from "./Board";
import { createBrowserHistory } from 'history';

class Ares extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        console.log("reconstructor");
        this.state={
            currentPage:"login",
            currentMainContent:"empty",
            currentNav:"Classic",
            account:'moore_huang@you-ce.net',
            email:'',
            password:'abc123' ,
            sid:'',
            startAt:new Date('1970-01-01 12:00:00'),
            endAt:new Date(),
            access_token:'',
            memberPage:1,
            memberData:[],
            nowPick:'',
        };
    }
    handleChange(event){//每一鍵輸入後觸發 檢查輸入字元
        const target=event.target;
        this.setState({
            [target.name]: target.value
        });
    }
    submitLogin(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        //------------------------------------------------------
        axios.post('/api/login',
            {
                email:this.state.account,
                password:this.state.password
            },
            {
                baseURL:'http://www.localhost.ares.net'
            })
            .then((result) => this.getSidFunc(result.data))
            .catch((error) => { console.error(error) })
    }
    submitLogin2(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        this.setState({
            sid:'Im in',
            currentPage:'home',
        });
    }
    getSidFunc(response){
        if(response.status===1){
            console.log("login success");
            let history=createBrowserHistory();
            // let history = this.props.history;
            history.push("/dashboard",true);
            // this.state.history.push("/dashboard");
            console.log(history);
            // window.location.href=window.location.origin+"/dashboard";
            this.setState({
                sid:'Im in',
                currentPage:'home',
                access_token:response.result.access_token
            });
            console.log("----------------------------");

        }else{
            console.log("login fail");
            alert("wrong account or password");
        }
    }
    postRequest(url, payload, onLoadFunc, onErrorFunc, bRetry){
        var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr.open("POST", url);
        xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-type', 'application/json');
        xhr.setRequestHeader('X-Requested-With', 'XMLHttpRequest');
        xhr.onload = function(event)
        {
            var jsonData = null;
            try
            {
                jsonData = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
                if (onLoadFunc)
                    onLoadFunc(jsonData);
            }
            catch(e)
            {
                console.log(e);
                console.log("xhr json error    bRetry: " + bRetry + "    data: \n" + xhr.responseText);
                if (bRetry)
                {
                    setTimeout(function()
                    {
                        this.postRequest(url, payload, onLoadFunc, onErrorFunc, bRetry);
                    }, 3000);
                }
            }
        };
        xhr.onerror = function(event)
        {
            console.log("xhr onerror    bRetry: " + bRetry);
            if (onErrorFunc)
                onErrorFunc(event);
            if (bRetry)
            {
                setTimeout(function()
                {
                    this.postRequest(url, payload, onLoadFunc, onErrorFunc, bRetry);
                }, 3000);
            }
        };

        xhr.send(JSON.stringify(payload));
    }


    render() {
        console.log("////////////");
        console.log(this.state);
        return (
            <Router>
                <Switch>
                    <Route exact={true} path="/">
                        <Login
                            submitLogin={(event) => this.submitLogin(event)}
                            submitLogin2={(event) => this.submitLogin2(event)}
                            handleChange={(event) => this.handleChange(event)}
                            account={this.state.account}
                            password={this.state.password}
                        />
                    </Route>
                    <Route exact={true} path="/dashboard">
                        <Board

                        />
                    </Route>
                </Switch>
            </Router>
        );
    }
}
// ========================================

ReactDOM.render(
    <Ares />,
    document.getElementById('root')
);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <link rel="icon" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/favicon.ico" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
    <meta name="theme-color" content="#000000" />
    <meta
      name="description"
      content="Web site created using create-react-app"
    />
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/logo192.png" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.ionicframework.com/ionicons/2.0.1/css/ionicons.min.css">

    <link rel="manifest" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/manifest.json" />

    <title>React App</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <noscript>You need to enable JavaScript to run this app.</noscript>
    <div id="root"></div>

  </body>
</html>
```

and here is the Login.js

```js
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import  { BrowserRouter as Router, Switch, Route, Link } from 'react-router-dom';

function Login(props) {
    console.log("renderLogin");
    return (
        <div className="hold-transition login-page">
            <div className="login-box">
                <div className="login-logo">
                </div>
                <div className="card">
                    <div className="card-body login-card-body">
                        <p className="login-box-msg">Sign in to start your session</p>
                        <form onSubmit={props.submitLogin}>
                            <div className="input-group mb-3">
                                <input
                                    type="email"
                                    className="form-control"
                                    placeholder="Email"
                                    onChange={props.handleChange}
                                    name={"account"}
                                    value={props.account}
                                />
                                <div className="input-group-append">
                                    <div className="input-group-text">
                                        <span className="fas fa-envelope"></span>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div className="input-group mb-3">
                                <input
                                    type="password"
                                    className="form-control"
                                    placeholder="Password"
                                    onChange={props.handleChange}
                                    name={"password"}
                                    value={props.password}
                                />
                                <div className="input-group-append">
                                    <div className="input-group-text">
                                        <span className="fas fa-lock"></span>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div className="row">
                                <div className="col-8">
                                    <div className="icheck-primary">
                                        <input type="checkbox" id="remember"/>
                                        <label htmlFor="remember">
                                            Remember Me
                                        </label>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div className="col-4">
                                    {/*<Link to='/dashboard'>*/}
                                        <button className="btn btn-primary btn-block">Sign In</button>
                                    {/*</Link>*/}
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </form>

                        <div className="social-auth-links text-center mb-3">
                            <p>- OR -</p>
                            <a onClick={props.submitLogin2}>
                                <i  className="fab fa-facebook mr-2"></i> Sign in using Facebook
                            </a>
                            <a href="#" className="btn btn-block btn-danger">
                                <i className="fab fa-google-plus mr-2"></i> Sign in using Google+
                            </a>
                        </div>

                        <p className="mb-1">
                            <a href="forgot-password.html">I forgot my password</a>
                        </p>
                        <p className="mb-0">
                            <a href="register.html" className="text-center">Register a new membership</a>
                        </p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    );
}

export default Login;
```

Comment: What's inside your `Board` component?

Comment: Sorry, I forget to post Board component.

The content of Board component is my dashboard page's JSX

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should first define your routes in your `App.js` like so:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './App.css';
import {BrowserRouter, Route, Redirect, Switch, withRouter,browserHistory} from 'react-router-dom';
import {Router} from 'react-router';
import Login from './Login';
import DashBoard from './DashBoard';

class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      
<div className="App">
<Switch>
    <Route exact path='/' component={Login} />
    <Route exact path='/DashBoard' component={DashBoard} />
  </Switch>
      </div>
   );
  }
}

export default withRouter(App);
```

Then , in your **Login.js**, `import { useHistory } from 'react-router-dom';`

inside **Login** function , `const history = useHistory();`

and after your submit API result `history.push('/DashBoard')`

> Now coming your second question **what's the advantage of using
> React-router compared to my old swich-case-render way?**

React router maintains the stack of your history, that makes it easier to navigate through your app, without have to worry about what routes user has taken. In single page apps, there is only single html page.we are reusing the same html page to render the different components based on the navigation. For details on react router I would suggest you going through [Getting started with React Router](https://codeburst.io/getting-started-with-react-router-5c978f70df91)

Hope that helps!!

Comment: 1. Haha thanks for you two guys' answer very much. I'm grateful. Although I need to combine both of your answer still make a little modification. Finally, it works
/n                                     
             2. And about the second question. So if I use switch-case to choose which whole page should be rendered, it is still SPA website right?(I thought it is, cuz I didn't reload the website. If that is, what's the advantage of  using React-router "more efficiency or securer" ? Or my knowledge is wrong?

Comment: your index.html is the one on which each page is painted in react. So yes, it is a SPA. If you will use your custom switch to render pages, you will not have history in stack, you will have to manually maintain that too, which is not recommended.

Answer (score 0):

please declare the history object outside of the class.
for example

```
const history = createBrowserHistory();
```

and then please change these lines

```
let history=createBrowserHistory();
history.push("/dashboard",true);

history.push("/dashboard")
```

Finally,

```
render() {
    console.log("////////////");
    console.log(this.state);
    return (
        <Router history={history}>
            <Switch>
```

In addition, I recommend that you should use Link instead of a tag

Comment: Haha thanks for you two guys' answer very much. I'm grateful. Although I need to combine both of your answer still make a little modification. Finally, it works